# Why does pyspark/serializers.py not release memory?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a folder which has a set of parquet files. My use-case is simple

1. Read the parquet file
2. Convert it into pandas.
3. Do some processing and show result per parquet file.

When I am iterating over a few of parquets, it works perfect.
But when I run it over hundreds of files, It crashes because of OOM errors.

Following is the code how I read parquet as pandas

```
def read_parquet_as_pandas(path, spark: SparkSession):
    df = spark.read.parquet(path).toPandas()
    df.sort_values('MY_INDEX', inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    return df
```

The above function gets called in a for loop like below

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[1]') \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "6g") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "10g")
    .getOrCreate()

for i in paths:
    df = read_parquet_as_pandas(i, spark)
```

The memory keeps piling up so I turned to [TraceMalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) to see where it's going, And all the snapshots had following line on top

```
python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py:587: size=9139 KiB (+9139 KiB), count=161624 (+161624), average=58 B
python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py:587: size=12.9 MiB (+4028 KiB), count=233156 (+71532), average=58 B
python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py:587: size=44.1 MiB (+31.2 MiB), count=796558 (+563402), average=58 B
```

As you can see it keeps on increasing ,

1. Why it's not releasing stuff from previous parquet files ?
2. How to release memory from it ?

Comment: try spark.catalog.clearCache() .... after every iteration.

Comment: Nope, It has no effect on the output.

Comment: in your for loop unpersist df for each iteration once your done processing that particular file